# Как получить ответ от json?

Tags: php, json

Пытаюсь из json получить нужные данные, пример json ответа:

```
$response = '[{"Open":true,"myprice":{"currency":"RUR","total":599.0},"title":"Заголовок."},{"Open":true,"myprice":{"currency":"RUR","total":99.0},"title":"Заголовок 2."}]';
```

`var_dump($response);` в начале отдает `string(1221) "[{"Open":true,"myprice":...`

Не получается получить даже одно значение:

currency,

total,

title.

Молчу о том, что их два, а может быть и 10.

Пытался вывести как обычно `echo  $response->myprice["total"];` но получаю ошибку

**Notice: Trying to get property 'myprice' of non-object**

Как правильно получить ответ?

Спасибо!

Comment: `$response[0]->myprice["total"]`

Comment: Тоже ошибку отдает Notice: Trying to get property 'myprice' of non-object in

Comment: `var_dump($response);` в начале отдает string(1221) "[{"Open":true,"myprice":...

Comment: Так это у Вас строка. Ее сначала надо преобразовать в объект/массив.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$response = '[{"Open":true,"myprice":{"currency":"RUR","total":599.0},"title":"Заголовок."},{"Open":true,"myprice":{"currency":"RUR","total":99.0},"title":"Заголовок 2."}]';

$response = json_decode($response, true);

echo $response[0]["myprice"]["total"];
```